# parseDate for Wireshark extract to use to plot receive window

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I have a wireshark extract (TSV) with two columns - "date" and "window" like

```
date    window
31:35.6 524288
31:35.6 524288
31:35.6 524288
31:35.6 524288
31:35.6 522024
31:35.6 
31:35.6 521452
...
```

I want to create a timeseries plot of "window" and was using the simple line chart (mbostock’s block #3883245) to start.  My index.html has only few edits from the example and results in an error message

> [19:12:43.516] TypeError: e is undefined @ file:///home/tim/Desktop/test/multiline-2/_attachments/d3.v3.min.js:2

I must be missing something - can you help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%M:%S.%L").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.window); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.window = +d.window;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.window; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error is on line 60:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, function() {*your graph stuff here*});
```

should be:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, function() {*your graph stuff here*});
```

so d3 knows that it is working with a .tsv file instead of .csv.

Converting your data file to .csv format should also get rid of this error, just make sure not to implement both fixes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank-you - foolish of me to get that wrong.  Still need to solve the PCAP UTC Epoch.nanoseconds to some time I could display for the x axis.  Notes on this site for converting epoch time will require some study by me